# Default Activity not found Waiting for process

Tags: java, android

When I am trying to debug-run my application I am getting this error in console:

```
Default Activity not foundWaiting for process: com.myapp.myapp
```

My AndroidManifest look like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.myapp.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.myapp.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Main" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828654/default-activity-not-found-in-android-studio) doesn't work for me because I can't find any sources tab as mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

For the second activity, in intent filter, change android:name to com.myapp.myapp.Main .