# Linux - Android Studio 1.1 Beta 3 - Default Activity not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am having trouble understanding how to apply a Default Activity to my Android Studio project in order for it to run without showing the 'Default Activity not found' error message in the run screen.

I have tried editing the build.gradle file to include a series of lines that some other Stack Overflow questions said to include. Here is the line that they said to include verbatim, I do not understand what  is supposed to be replaced with.

```
sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/<YOUR DIRECTORY>'
}
```

I have tried using the paths `'src/main'`, `'src/main/java'`, `'src/main/com/todo/project'`, `'src/main/java/com/todo/project'` as well as some various other lines.

My project package path is `'com.todo.project'`.

If anyone has any suggestions or solutions to my problem, please let me know. I will continue to update this question with any findings that might help you come to an answer. Thank you in advance for your help and consideration.

Comment: Did you look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828654/default-activity-not-found-in-android-studio that recommended adding the intent filter to your manifest? The answers you're seeing that suggest messing with the build scripts may be red herrings for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run/Debug Configuration
In module app (or your named module): From left panel. Do these steps:

Activity -> Launch -> Browse -> Search you name of your start up activity. Or chose tab project -> Point to main -> java ->  -> start up activity
=> It's work for me! It's weird cause i create new project with default template and happened this issue  !