# Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

when running my app it always goes to the edit configuration. 
i found a solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828654/default-activity-not-found-in-android-studio) but couldn't find the source tab in open module settings. Is there any other way to solve this? I'm using the latest version of android studio.
Thank you for the help.

this is my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mobapp.yurin.hkt">

<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Have you set Default Activity in your Manifest file?

Comment: yes i think I already have

Comment: let's have a look at Manifest file first

Comment: i put my AndroidManifest on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't set the default launcher for the application. Try this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I'm having an NullPointerException :(

Comment: Gradle build finished with 1 error(s) in 1 min 1 sec
NullPointerException: null
Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.