# Android Application Error while running the Application

Tags: java, android

Whenever I try running my application - this window in the screenshot is popping up in my screen. Stating that default activity is not found because of this I am not able to deploy my app:

[image]

Manifest file of my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mcs.oodoeg" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android3.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sigin"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is what the window which I am getting while clicking the Run-> Edit Congiguration:

[image]

Gradle file of my code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mcs.oodoeg"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile files('libs/xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
}
```

Comment: Please add some clarity- what window is popping up?  Is this a result of a recent change you made to some code?  It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: it is because configuration to the app is messed up, you gotta fix that first before you run the app

Comment: i din make any changes in my code certainly when i tried deploying  the application in my device it popped up that window in my screenshot

Answer (score 34):

I had a similar problem, the issue was the device.

When you **uninstalled** the app (to install it again after running project), instead of actually uninstalling it, it **deactivated** it.

That means, the app was still installed but it was blocked by OS.

So I couldn't run the project, and no more information was given. (`Activity launcher not found` was the only message)

Effectively deleting the app (going through device settings) solved the issue.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. so you just have to go to Settings > Apps > your app > Uninstall instead of dragging it from launcher

Comment: This worked for me too, on my Android phone I have multiple profiles

Comment: The app is already uninstalled but it is still giving error while installing and as it is uninstalled it is not being listed in App List

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs when you delete the app when you are still testing it on your phone. The app shows as deleted because it disappears from your launcher, To fully delete the app follow the steps below.

It worked perfectly after clicking on settings => Apps & notification => App info => find the name of the app => on top right corner click on the three dots => Uninstall for all users.

Comment: I am not able to find this setting on MI phone....If anyone can help?

Answer (score 5):

**try this if you upgrade android studio IDEA**

**File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**
ref. link=> [Default Activity not found in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828654/default-activity-not-found-in-android-studio)

Comment: @HariPriya Please check gradle file plugins.. like this => apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: and please post your gradle also

Comment: Have posted my gradle file

Comment: who give down vote?? please can you tell me.? why you give down vote?

Answer (score 4):

It's working perfectly for me after clicking on settings => Apps & notification => App info => find the name of the app => on top right corner click on the three dots => Uninstall for all users.

Comment: oh, You saved me

Comment: @TanveerMunir, If this helped you, then upvote the answer please

Comment: I did that before your saying

Answer (score 2):

it's studio setting problem. please click app => Edit Configrations => Deploy. select Default apk and apply.after click ok

Answer (score 1):

1. Restart your IDE.
2. Clean your project, goto **Build > Clean Project**.
3. Run again and see if your error is resolved.

Go to **Run > Edit configuration**  and check this detail.
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAvkH.png)

Comment: I did this clean build several times but still it is not resolved

Comment: did you define main activity code in manifest.xml as launcher?? plz post your manifest code..

Comment: Now go to run-> edit config. and check for this detail. launch -- default activity?

Comment: It seems like every thing okay.. now just check gradle dependency .. if it is not done.. Make new Project and copy every resource file and java file as it location.. It may be defiantly solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

Solved by going to the other user account on my phone and uninstall the app.
Seems this problem is caused by first installing this app on "A" user account then we uninstall this app in "B" account. So when we try to run our app again in "B" account the old app is still exist in "A" account.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the app on my device for other user.

- when you run the app on your device installation will happen for every user on your device
- uninstalling the app only uninstall it for the current user you are using on the device

Comment: I have also same problem, Just go to other user and uninstall it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was due to the emulator which started in "safe mode" making impossible to run on the device, changing emulator device worked.

Answer (score 0):

just find the application on your phone and Uninstall it.

and Clean the app and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers above didn't help me. Renaming the activity worked for me. For example, ErrorActivity threw this error. ErrActivity - no. [image]

[image]