# Android Instant App : Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

This seems to be manifest merging error. I'm trying to port existing code to instant app module. What I've tried is :

1. Changed main app module to baseFeatureModule.
2. Created a new module completeApp.
3. Emptied completeAppModule's Manifest :
4. added implementation project entry in completeAppModule

   implementation project (":udofy")
5. Added these entries in base module :

   baseFeature true in android block

   application project (":fullModule") in dependencies

I've tried rebuilding/ invalidate cache and restart/ Restarting studio but no help. Can anybody help me out here?

Comment: Your “Edit Configuration” could be missing something. Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found/32665255#32665255

Comment: Also, double check that you haven’t missed any important steps while converting your existing app to AIA-project. Refer to
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/index.html#0 or https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps

Comment: I'm having this issue too. It's really weird because sometimes a fresh check out from the git repository will cause the app to build perfectly and then after a few changes android studio is no longer able to determine the default activity.

Comment: I had the same issue , Finally fixed it by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520342/969201)

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18828654/default-activity-not-found-in-android-studio), there is no sources tab in later versions of Android Studio. However, you can edit the `build.gradl`e file instead. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22028681/1101730). Also make sure that you have specified the default activity in your `AndroidManisfest.xml` file. Within your default activity's xml section, [there should be these tags](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/error-in-android-studio-default-activity-not-found):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was using crashlytics and another debug utility that do not play well with instant apps. This was causing the manifest merging to fail. When I removed Crashlytics and the other utility, the manifest for the APK was able to be successfully generated and Android Studio was able to find the default activity which was present in the base feature.

Comment: were you able to narrow this down any further?  I'm seeing same issue that I think might also be related to crashlytics (though only happens for me in Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that the Manifest merger failed with the Firebase plugin in the base module.

**Option 1:**

I fixed this by adding following to the base modules 'AndroidManifest.xml'.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:authorities="mypackage.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        tools:node="merge"/>
```

Don't forget to replace `mypackage`.

**Option 2:**

Copy the whole `<application ...>...</application>` tag into app modules `AndroidManifest.xml`