# Create Instant app for existing application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-instant-apps

I have an application that I want to create an `instantApp` for it.
I successfully apply changes to my project and it builds successfully.

But there is 2 problem:
-I couldn't run the application and the error is:

```
Default Activity not found
```

[image]

And another problem is that when I run the `instantApp` I see an error message  that says `Google Play Store has stoped`

[image]

I have an `app` and two `Instant App Feature Module` that are `base` and `feature`.

And these is my feature manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="instantapp.samples.yaramobile.com.base.feature">

    <application tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name=".presenter.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                    android:autoVerify="true"
                    android:order="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

                <data android:host="test.com"/>
                <data android:pathPattern="/"/>
                <data android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".presenter.display.DisplayActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".presenter.display.PermissionActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Regarding "Default Activity not Found", check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862821, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120608 posts.

Comment: For your `Google Play Store has stopped` issue, it's best if you split this off to a new question, and you should provide a stacktrace from your logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problems and solutions:

The problem was about AppCompact dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

there was a conflict and I had to use of `api` instead of `implementation`

```
api 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

and there was another conflict with room dependencies:

```
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
 kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
 implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02'
 kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha02'
```

I had to replaced with `api` too:

```
 api 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
 kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0'
 api 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha02'
 kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha02'
```

Another problem was about `databinding`
I Just added `databinding` in my base module but it's needed in installed module too:

```
  dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
```

and again is about `room`:
I had to add a provider into the `manifest` of the base module because I had an error in merge manifest in my `installed` module because of these provider that is used in `room` dependencies:

```
<provider
        tools:replace="android:authorities"
        android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer"
        android:authorities="codenevisha.ir.mvvmwithdagger.base.lifecycle-process"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true"/>
```

don't forget to replace this provider with adding             `tools:replace="android:authorities"`

Hope these guidelines will you too.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found), if you see that error occur after upgrading versions of IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio, or after Generating a new APK, you may need to refresh the IDE's cache.

> `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...`

It also means that you don't have an activity declared in AndroidManifest.xml that is marked as the main activity to be launched when the application starts.