# Is it possible to integrate android annotations with android studio 0.4.6?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

I tried many options from google and stackoverflow. 
Android studio 0.4.6 and aa 2.7.1. 
My build.gradle looks like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
ext.daggerVersion = '1.0.0';
ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '2.7.1';

configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    apt "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    compile "com.googlecode.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${androidAnnotationsVersion}"
    apt "com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
    compile "com.squareup.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
}
```

I've checked Activities_ in AndroidManifest.xml too.

If this quesion were not banned due to other "similar" questions I would prefer answers from people who did it with exacly the same `as` version. I know there will be next version's and maybe new questions but this looks litle tricky imho. Even though android development with aa is very robust.

"sync project with gradle files", clean, rebuild etc brings no effect.

**EDIT:**

I tryied with

```
ext.daggerVersion = '1.2.0';
ext.androidAnnotationsVersion = '3.0.1';
```

but it brings no result.

After switching to:
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
and 
    ext.daggerVersion = '1.2.0';

it builds succesfully but outputs with:

```
Default Activity not found
```

I checked [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found) with no effect.

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly?

Comment: "Error running app: Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again."

Comment: I don't see that you put dependency to 'android-apt' plugin and applied it

Comment: Also latest android gradle plugin is '0.8.6' already

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add the android-apt dependency within the BuildScript dependencies and let gradle know to use it as a plugin.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
```

This is my apt config section, you may need other settings but this should get you started

```
apt {
arguments {
    resourcePackageName android.defaultConfig.packageName
    androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
}
}
```

Lot's more info here: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt