# My app closes on start in the emulator. What's wrong?

Tags: android, crash, emulation

This is My MainActivity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {   }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


        final MediaPlayer sButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.turkey_gobbling);


        Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.call);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


Every time I run my app it crashes and I can't find a solution, and my code looks fine.
Here is my `MainActivity.xml` and my Manifest file. I've searched hours for this and now I find errors in `ActivityThread.java`, `Method.java` and `Activity.java`

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android.mrbowe.turkeycall" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.android.mrbowe.turkeycall.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

My  activity_main.xml file here

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".MainActivity"
 android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher">

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Call_that_Turkey"
    android:id="@+id/call"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:background="#fff6edff" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

This activity_main is my MAIN and only layout
My dependencies go to app compact and google play services

Comment: Can we see your Logcat?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the onActivityCreated method. This is where you'll build and load the AdRequest. Reference the AdView, then build and load the AdRequest. Not in OnCreate. For example:

```
  /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view. This fragment
     * would include your content.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class makes the ad request and loads the ad.
     */
    public static class AdFragment extends Fragment {

        private AdView mAdView;

        public AdFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

            // Gets the ad view defined in layout/ad_fragment.xml with ad unit ID set in
            // values/strings.xml.
            mAdView = (AdView) getView().findViewById(R.id.adView);

            // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
            // get test ads on a physical device. e.g.
            // "Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("ABCDEF012345") to get test ads on this device."
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .build();

            // Start loading the ad in the background.
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
        }

        /** Called when leaving the activity */
        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.pause();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        /** Called when returning to the activity */
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.resume();
            }
        }

        /** Called before the activity is destroyed */
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (mAdView != null) {
                mAdView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    }
}
```

See [Reference Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) - They suggest to use a fragment to wrap the AdView.

Comment: Assuming you followed the tutorial, installed Google Play services, update the build-gradle, checked dependencies, ... See if any of those solutions help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)