# App is not launching

Tags: java, android-studio

What can I do to get my app to launch?

It has the Icon on the device screen but as soon as I try to open it, it displays a message saying the app has stopped working. I am using Android Studio. Below is a copy of the Android Monitor message it displays when I try to open the app.

> 11-25 16:56:49.724 25383-25383/com.firstapp.colton.myfirstapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.firstapp.colton.myfirstapp, PID: 25383
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.firstapp.colton.myfirstapp/com.firstapp.colton.myfirstapp.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2334)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                       at
>   com.firstapp.colton.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) 
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
>                                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: possibly you app need launch activity default

http://stackoverflow.com/a/33182293/3741698

Comment: Code would definitely help.  Especially MainActivity.java line 22.

Comment: you can show the code MainActivity.java ?

Comment: Not much to go on without the code on MainActivity.java.  Please post said code here.