# emulator crashing, android

Tags: android, crash

New day, new problem. Now it's about emulator. I'm starting it, and then it gives me the error:

```
12-05 18:25:42.460 2735-2735/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
12-05 18:25:42.610 2735-2735/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
12-05 18:25:42.610 2735-2735/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
12-05 18:25:42.630 2735-2735/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-05 18:25:42.650 1307-1343/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.android.defcontainer for service com.android.defcontainer/.DefaultContainerService: pid=2745 uid=10003 gids={50003, 9997, 1028, 1015, 1023, 2001, 1035} abi=x86_64
12-05 18:25:42.700 2745-2758/com.android.defcontainer D/DefContainer: Copying /data/local/tmp/com.example.pablo.appcontacts to base.apk
12-05 18:25:42.710 1307-1343/system_process W/PackageParser: No actions in intent filter at /data/app/vmdl505409062.tmp/base.apk Binary XML file line #22
12-05 18:25:42.780 1307-1343/system_process D/PackageManager: Renaming /data/app/vmdl505409062.tmp to /data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1
12-05 18:25:42.800 1307-1343/system_process I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1@base.apk@classes.dex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
12-05 18:25:42.800 1307-1343/system_process I/art: DexFile_isDexOptNeeded failed to open oat file '/data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1/x86_64/base.odex' for file location '/data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1/base.apk': Failed to open oat filename for reading: No such file or directory
12-05 18:25:42.800 1307-1343/system_process I/PackageManager: Running dexopt on: /data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1/base.apk pkg=com.example.pablo.appcontacts isa=x86_64 vmSafeMode=false
12-05 18:25:42.810 2761-2761/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
12-05 18:25:42.810 2761-2761/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=5 --zip-location=/data/app/com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1/base.apk --oat-fd=6 --oat-location=/data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/data@app@com.example.pablo.appcontacts-1@base.apk@classes.dex --instruction-set=x86_64 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
12-05 18:25:42.910 2761-2761/? W/dex2oat: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
12-05 18:25:44.440 2761-2761/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 1.630s (threads: 1)
12-05 18:25:44.500 1307-1343/system_process V/BackupManagerService: restoreAtInstall pkg=com.example.pablo.appcontacts token=1 restoreSet=0
12-05 18:25:44.500 1307-1343/system_process V/BackupManagerService: Finishing install immediately
12-05 18:25:44.500 1307-1343/system_process W/Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
12-05 18:25:44.510 1307-1307/system_process D/BackupManagerService: Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.pablo.appcontacts flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
12-05 18:25:44.520 1307-1406/system_process I/InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2763/com.google.android.gms D/PackageBroadcastService: Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.example.pablo.appcontacts
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2097/com.google.android.gms D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.games from APK com.google.android.gms
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2097/com.google.android.gms D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.gass from APK com.google.android.gms
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2097/com.google.android.gms D/AsyncTaskServiceImpl: Submit a task: h
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2097/com.google.android.gms D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.gass from APK com.google.android.gms
12-05 18:25:44.540 2097-2097/com.google.android.gms D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Loading module com.google.android.gms.vision from APK com.google.android.gms
12-05 18:25:44.550 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/h: Processing package: com.example.pablo.appcontacts
12-05 18:25:44.560 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/a: Look up (com.example.pablo.appcontacts:1) returned no result
12-05 18:25:44.560 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/h: Starting Hash for package com.example.pablo.appcontacts:1.0
12-05 18:25:44.570 2097-2765/com.google.android.gms I/PeopleContactsSync: CP2 sync disabled
12-05 18:25:44.590 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/h: Package com.example.pablo.appcontacts's hash: 8c78fa7722020163ebfd189fd835f8ba29bdd0dd71333d0e7a8254b199fa5d40
12-05 18:25:44.590 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/a: Look up (com.example.pablo.appcontacts:1) returned no result
12-05 18:25:44.600 1307-1325/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=2767 uid=10041 gids={50041, 9997, 1028, 1015} abi=x86_64
12-05 18:25:44.620 2097-2764/com.google.android.gms D/h: Saved the app info in cache for package:com.example.pablo.appcontacts.
12-05 18:25:44.630 1307-1332/system_process W/VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
12-05 18:25:44.720 1307-1343/system_process I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 50802(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 25(731KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 9MB/13MB, paused 0 total 210ms
12-05 18:25:44.720 2735-2735/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-05 18:25:44.730 2735-2737/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
12-05 18:25:44.730 1307-1596/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 1975:com.android.externalstorage/u0a6 (adj 15): empty #17
12-05 18:25:44.750 1307-1595/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10006/pid_1975/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
12-05 18:25:48.090 2022-2022/com.google.process.gapps V/GLSActivity: AuthDelegateWrapperCreated with selected intent: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.DefaultAuthDelegateService }
12-05 18:25:48.090 2022-2022/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser: [DeviceKeyStore] Cannot load key: Device key file not found.
12-05 18:25:48.130 2527-2555/com.google.android.gms.unstable I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode: java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:111)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:130)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.a(SourceFile:376)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.<init>(SourceFile:194)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder.<init>(SourceFile:38)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.common.data.i.a(SourceFile:1038)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.config.ConfigService.b(SourceFile:1188)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.config.h.a(SourceFile:1639)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.config.h.a(SourceFile:1570)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at com.google.android.gms.config.internal.q.onTransact(SourceFile:59)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/StrictMode:     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
12-05 18:25:48.160 2022-2033/com.google.process.gapps E/DataBuffer: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (internal object: com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataHolder@25996c1a)
12-05 18:25:48.170 957-957/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV: Widevine DRM not supported on this device
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV: android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at android.media.MediaDrm.<init>(MediaDrm.java:180)
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.p.run(SourceFile:99)
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-05 18:25:48.210 2527-2793/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-05 18:25:48.240 2022-2798/com.google.process.gapps D/GetConfigurationSnapshotOperation: no corresponding serverToken: com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader, 1, 
12-05 18:25:48.270 2022-2791/com.google.process.gapps I/PhenotypeFlagCommitter: Experiment Configs successfully retrieved for com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader
12-05 18:25:48.280 2022-2791/com.google.process.gapps W/Uploader:  no longer exists, so no auth token.
12-05 18:25:48.280 2022-2798/com.google.process.gapps D/GetCommittedConfigurationOperation: no corresponding serverToken: com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader
12-05 18:25:48.600 2527-2555/com.google.android.gms.unstable I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.ccc.abuse.droidguard.DroidGuard>
12-05 18:25:48.700 957-957/? E/Drm: Failed to find drm plugin
12-05 18:25:48.820 2022-2801/com.google.process.gapps D/GetCommittedConfigurationOperation: no corresponding serverToken: com.google.android.gms.playlog.uploader
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser: [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser: java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:268)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
12-05 18:25:50.110 2022-2792/com.google.process.gapps W/GLSUser:     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.at.run(SourceFile:142)
12-05 18:25:53.710 1307-2182/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 1885:com.android.printspooler/u0a42 (adj 15): empty #17
12-05 18:25:53.720 1307-1595/system_process W/libprocessgroup: failed to open /acct/uid_10042/pid_1885/cgroup.procs: No such file or directory
```

My app is targetting SKD 21. I've tried using emulators running on 19, 21 and 23 and they were always launching, but with no reactions towards app.

Any advices?:)

Comment: It seems, that the path to memtrack is incorrect or the file simply doesn't exist there

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question in my case was the SECOND one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found). It looks like after switching `target SDK` from 23 to 21, something wrong happened to my manifest and I haven't noticed that. I was missing that part with action `MAIN` which was the problem.