# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE]

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I am using Android studio .I have changed application ID still not working,please share any concrete answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` remove `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` when debugging and if you need it put it back when generating an apk.

Comment: after removed android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" ,It Show Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not foundWaiting for process: com.develop.app

Comment: Clean-Rebuild and run

Comment: Also if that doesn't solve your problem then check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27856933/1889768).

Comment: What do you mean by **sharedUserId**?  Did OP say he has that.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No but the error is usually generated by **sharedUserId** in `Manifest.`