# "Error running app: Default Activity not Found"

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, main-activity

I'm programming an app with sqlite+JSON, but suddenly I couldn't Run it anymore, and it popped this message, here's my `AndroidManifest.xml` , Idk if there's something wrong with it, my main activity is called `DatosActivity`, I wish you could help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hitan.practica2_u3">

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.hitan.practica2_u3.DatosActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: kindly post error message.

Comment: looking at your manifest intent filter is missing , add it and then try again

Comment: Please clear your question? or update your error log here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **`category.LAUNCHER`** & **`action.MAIN`** .

```
 <activity 
       android:name="com.example.hitan.practica2_u3.DatosActivity"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
          >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this intent filter inside your activity tag

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.hitan.practica2_u3.DatosActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because you have not added the default screen which should execute first. So try adding following code snippet, and your problem will be solved:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.hitan.practica2_u3.DatosActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please Add Intent Filter Tag in Manifest To Make It Default while Launching.