# Android Studio Build doesn't recognize my MainActivity (Tried all the propositions)

Tags: android, xml, intellij-idea, android-activity

I try to run the app in Android Studio but I get an Error: Default Activity not Found, I have come through all the solutions proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found) and none of them worked for me so I Set the launch configuration to a Specified Activity as in the picture:
[image]

But when I hit Run I get the error Activity not Found in the manifest file :
[image]

here is my full Manifest Declaration:

[image]

Comment: The manifest xml you posted is malformed at "MainActivity", is this really your manifest?

Comment: what's wrong about it?

Comment: Missing `"` after the name. The XML would not parse.

Comment: thanks i deleted it when i was trying to indent it for posting

Comment: Ok. Is the space inside our outside the `""` quotes?

Comment: check the picture

Comment: Why are you trying to start _specified activity_ instead of _default activity_ in your run configuration?

Comment: because it didn;t work, it shows the error i linked to in top of the question

Answer (score 0):

You only need the Activity name inside package

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity >
       <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: specifying full package name will work too although not required

Answer (score 0):

Try create another activity by android studio and check in the lancher home delete in your manifest this intent filter. Maybe this activity has some corrupted and Android studio dont recognize that

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Comment: Please remove the <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

Answer (score 0):

Check if your MainActvity extends AppCompactActivity

Or

May be you are using a wrong package name to register activity.
Check both.