# Getting error after updating android studio to 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

We are facing an error of default activity is not found after update android studio to version "3.2". On another PC, which is running lower version 3.1.4 of android studio, this same application is working. If anyone has a solution then please suggest us.

I have attached manifest file of screen shot of android studio for that error.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.exmple.com">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

</activity>

<activity android:name=".Category_item"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

<activity android:name=".ImageDatail"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>

<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
android:screenOrientation="portrait">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>


</intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="your-own-uri" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<service android:name=".FireBase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
android:exported="true"
android:stopWithTask="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".FireBase.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
android:exported="true"
android:stopWithTask="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver
android:name=".Util.ConnectivityReceiver"
android:enabled="true">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.qualifiedapps.inspirationalquotes.fileprovider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you try File->Invalidate caches / restart already?

Comment: Yes but no luck

Comment: Close android studio, move/rename ".idea" folder in your project root, restart android studio.

Comment: Yes, i have tried to rename that folder and build again but still getting same error.

Comment: Try remove this line `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>` from first intent filter in splash screen..

Comment: Still not working... Any other solution then please suggest us

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)