# Could not identify launch Activity

Tags: android, android-studio

have had this problem for a while  I just installed android studio and I have been having this problem:

Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity

... I have this problem with existing projects MyApp I tried to make new project but the same error still

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.app.myapplication">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: Is `MainActivity` the name of your activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: yes MainActivity is the name of activity

Comment: i try all the answer nothing work for me @UmerFarooq

Comment: @EnaamRiyadh is MainActivity in the same directory as your manifest file?

Comment: @EamonScullion see the picture please

Comment: Instead of this <activity android:name=".MainActivity"> Give <activity android:name="package_name.MainActivity">

Comment: @Varma i already did that not working

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...