# Android Studio doesn't see Android specific classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I tried with `Invalidate caches / restart`, i tried cleaning the project, rebuilding, syncing with Gradle ... nothing works. Android studio just went berzerk. And it's for all projects, not just this one

[image]

**Everything's red !**

[image]

**These are set properly ... i guess..**

[image]

**This is the version i'm using**

[image]

**Ideas ?! I can't work like this**

**EDIT**

Also ... this seems to be happening on a project... what is going on ?!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps helps

Close your project, and

in your project folder delete project/.idea

Delete ~/.gradle folder.

Open the project again.
Everything should be solved.

**Edit**: as a last resort reinstall the IDE"

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I got the "Default Activity not found" and i invalidated the cache/restart, i don't get it, but it's back the same problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found    see the third answer

Comment: Nope...doesn't work. Nothing works. Everything's still red, it can't find anything ....

Comment: create a new project and see if it fixes your issue

Comment: Well, i need it to work for existing projects as well.
I just uninstalled android studio, reinstalling it again... it's gonna take a while ... will let you know.

Comment: well that certainly would solve the problem , however i was asking to know whether the problem is cuz some files got deleted of your app or the studio itself

Comment: Yeah, i figured that's why you were asking. But i got fed up with it so i reinstalled it. Seems to be fine now, but i don't wanna jinx it. Thank you for your help, please edit your answer with "Edit: as a last resort reinstall the IDE" and I'll accept it. Your solution worked, but in my case only partially/temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

1. invalidate cache/restart
2. clean build
3. close and reopen project