# Android Studio : Error running 'app' Default activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm new to android studio and doing my first project.  I made changes to my layout xml file after which getting the above mentioned error. i didn't add any new activity and also the android `manifest.xml` file has default activity mentioned.

I have tried to invalidate the cache and restart the Android studio but still the error exists and I'm not able to execute my program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: What's your error? Can you please attach the screen shot of the error log

Comment: Put your crash Log Here

Comment: Have added this line of code in your default activity?
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33182293/4649110

Comment: @Iqbal honnur problem got Resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it from "app" -> "Configurations"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario You have missed by telling the manifest about Which activity to run, Like I have Removed these Lines From Menifest

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This error will accour, Just add the above Lines in menifest and Your error will Gone.

Like I have tested By removing the above line for Yourself from Menifest I face the Error just Like You..
[image: Error Image]

Here the main Activity will be the One You want to start First After Installation Of Apk