# Android Studio Error running 'app': Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio 3.4.2 on macOS 10.14.5. Every time I try to run my app, I get the following error:

```
Error running 'app': Default Activity not found
```

I tried this solution already ([Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)) but it didn't help.

Any help?

Comment: Have you added ACTION_MAIN intent filter.

Comment: Try After Clean Project, Build > Clean Project

Comment: yeah I did clean project multiple times already @SagarPoshiya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Invalidate Caches/Restart` did not help you, then
maybe you forget to declare Your Activity in Manifest

```
   <activity android:name="your.package.YourDefaultActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Try to add this into your manifest, This lines of code tell the system from which activity Application should start, like an entering point of your app

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register your default activity

```
 <activity
        android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""  >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also make sure your selected module & default activity is correct

[image]