# Android Studio 3.5 ...Getting the error default activity not found after upgraded

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

***I Just upgraded android studio*** :

```
Android Studio 3.5
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312, built on August 9, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

**I am getting the error**:

```
11:35   Error running 'app': Default Activity not found
```

**I tried all possible solutions like**

1. Invalidate caches restart
2. clean and rebuild
3. deleting cache folder of android studio
4. Default activity is mentioned in manifest

I also tried solution in this questions, didn't work: 
[***https://stackoverflow.com/q/15825081/1083093***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15825081/1083093)

*This was working before until I upgraded the android studio*

Comment: Can you post `AndroidManifest.xml` and `build.gradle` file in the question? Also, double-check the `Project Structure` feature in Android studio and see if everything is configured properly

Comment: Try re-importing the project.

Comment: @karan .... Reimporting didnt work ! ....

Comment: @RahulKhurana .... Both files are correct since i could run these until i upgraded

Comment: did you do file -> new -> import project or just selected file->open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issues a few days ago. Below is what I'd done:

Delete all the files & folder under

1. `Project directory > .idea > libraries`
2. `Project directory > .idea > caches`
3. `Project directory > app > build`

**Make sure to close the AndroidStudio** and delete all the files manually.

Answer (score 3):

I have spend almost 5 hours and got the solution. I have copy that project and run in another system then its working fine, So just do following solution to fix this issue and it is work for me and i hope some one will get help with this.
Solution :

Delete the cash from your `%Home%\.gradle\cash` and sync project again.
Also check that is there any duplicate tag in your Manifest.

**On Windows:** `%USER_HOME%\.gradle/caches/`
**On Mac/Unix:** `$HOME/.gradle/caches/`

This issue was in android studio 3.2

**Note**: `Android Studio's File | Invalidate Caches/Restart` doesn't clear the Android build cache, so you'll have to clean it separately.

On Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

On Mac or Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: I closed Android Studio and deleted `C:\Users\<my-user-name>\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches` directory.

Optionally, you might want to delete all the latest directories in here: `C:\Users\<my-user-name>\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding.
- Invalidating caches and restarting.
- Deleting cache folder of Android Studio

These way can not work for me.

I just **removed all the code in the application label in the manifest file except for launcher activity** and it worked!

Then you just revert your change.