# Android install uninstalled apk

Tags: android, android-studio

So I added this functionality of reading  filesystem. When I debugged it on my android, there was a NullPointerException, so after some googling (on StackOverflow) I found that I need to add permission to the manifest file. After doing this, I rebuilt it many times, but it seems that after running it on my phone, it was not properly updated, because the NPE persisted. that's why I decided to manually (using Samsung's option ) uninstall it, hoping it will be reinstalled by Android Studio.

Sadly after that action, I cannot run this application anymore.

```
Default Activity not found
```

I don't see this application in apps list neither in main menu. I tried also

```
adb install ...pathtoapk...
```

But it says it is already installed

```
adb -r install ...pathtoapk...
```

Also does not work, says it is installed correctly, but app is still not visible neither in menu nor app list

Comment: I restarted my computer and phone many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

Comment: Besides, adding the permission into `AndroidManifest.xml` (which you might have corrupted, when editing it) is not enough, these have to be requested at run-time, since Marshmallow. Without some default `Activity`, there might be no launcher icon in the app drawer.

Answer (score 0):

if the error is Default Activity not found then you have to add this code in your launcher activity (whatever activity is launching first)

```
        `<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>`
```

Or if problem is with permissions then use   [Dexter library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter) or if still there is an error then share your logcat

Comment: I have these line in manifest. I just created another application and installed it and ran using Android Studio. Then I uninstalled it from Android level, and now I cannot install it again. This is repeatable.