# Every time when i open class teacher's project to my system it shows this error.Error running app: Default activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

[image: Error]

I'm a beginner in Android.
Every time when I open class teacher's project to my system it shows this error.

```
Error running app: Default activity not found.
```

What should I do to match the same project as my teacher's?
I've tried many solutions.

[image: Menu-->Build-->Clean Project[![Menu-->Invalidate Cache and restart]

[image: Clean Project[![Menu-->Invalidate Cache and restart]

My Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.assigncheckbox">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: May you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Default Activity Not Found" on Android Studio upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/default-activity-not-found-on-android-studio-upgrade)

Comment: @LucaMurra I've posted that

Answer (score 1):

maybe it happen because you didn't add this activity to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
  <activity
            android:name=".yourActivity"
             />
```