# Android Studio is showing an error when I press the run button

Tags: android-studio

I have been following a YouTube tutorial on 2D Game development and when I pressed the run button to check, it shows:

> Error runing "app": Default Activity not found

Also it shows an error on AndroidMainfest.xml if I use landscape instead of fullsensor:

```xml
<activity android:name=".GameActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.noActionBar"></activity>
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.noActionBar"></activity>
```

Comment: What error does it show on landscape?

Comment: @CoolMind it says

Expecting android : screenOrientation= "unspecified" or "fullsensor" for this activity so the user can use the application in any orientation and provide a great experience Chorme OS devices

Comment: You can remove `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` at all.

Comment: @CoolMind    sorry!!  what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that `screenOrientation` is an optional attribute. You can delete a whole string `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` or retain it, if you wish. I suppose, that was not an error, but a warning.

Comment: oh well thanks a lot

Comment: Good luck! :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `intent-filter`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And why `@style/AppTheme.noActionBar`? Use `@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar`.

See also ["Default Activity Not Found" on Android Studio upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/default-activity-not-found-on-android-studio-upgrade).