# why does Android Studio not recognize functions?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I did not change anything in my code, nor in the grade file, but I clicked on the update gradle notification android studio gets from time to time. I am not sure what the problem is but suddenly the IDE does not recognize some functions anymore, like String methods

[image]

[image]

[image]

also this icon changed:

[image]

My old project runs, but when I create a new project it won't work it says:
Error running 'app': Default Activity not found.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: [Duplicate] please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/default-activity-not-found-on-android-studio-upgrade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to C:\Users\{user}\.AndroidStudio4.0\system
and delete the caches folder.

Tried a lot of things I found online, but only this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue I tried closing android down and restarted it up again and it started working, couldn't tell you why it happened though.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it from the Build Option. I have experienced this a lot of time as well. This works for me. As to why it works, I am not sure it. Hopefully someone would soon pitch in.